# Using useRef hook, modify CSS style for a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change the style of a react component using the useRef hook and this is what I did so far,

I used the react hook useRef so that I can refer to the component that I want to change its style by clicking on the two buttons.

But I am not getting any response when clicking on the two buttons.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, {useRef}from 'react'
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
import DropdownList from './components/DropdownList';
import Card from './components/Card/Card';
import data from './utils/data';


const App = ()=>{

    const element = useRef(null);

    const gridView =()=>{
        // to be implemented
        element.current.style.display ="inline-block"
        
    }


    const listView = ()=>{
        // to be implemented
        element.current.style.display ="row";
    }


    return(
        <div style={{width:500}}>
            <h1>Product Catalog</h1>
            <DropdownList/>
            <SearchBox />
            <div>
                <button onClick={listView}>
                    <span>Switch to ListView</span>
                </button>

                <button onClick={gridView}>
                    <span>Switch to GridView</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {data.products.map((product)=> <Card ref={element} src={product.getImage()}/>)}
            
    
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should instead go for state and CSS classes. State determines the element's classes which ultimately determines the style of the element.

Comment: I tried it using document.getElementById but still not getting a response

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the ref to each object in product list. I doubt you can have multiple dom objects with the same useRef.

The following snippet worked for me after some adjustements.
However I am only changing the color of the listed items with css.

```
import React, {useRef}from 'react'

const data = {
  products: [
    {
      name: 'foo',
    },
    {
      name: 'boo',
    },
    {
      name: 'coo',
    },
  ]
}


const App = ()=>{

    const element = useRef(null);

    const gridView =()=>{
        element.current.style.color ="black"
        
    }


    const listView = ()=>{
        element.current.style.color ="white";
    }


    return(
        <div style={{width:500}}>
            <h1>Product Catalog</h1>
            <div>
                <button onClick={listView}>
                    <span>Switch to ListView</span>
                </button>

                <button onClick={gridView}>
                    <span>Switch to GridView</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div ref={element}>
            {data.products.map((product)=> <div>{product.name}</div>)}
            </div>
    
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i tried using mostly your same exact code but sill not getting a response